# AMD64 calling convention; __m512 operand on the stack

Tags: assembly, x86-64, callstack, abi, avx512

I'm trying to understand AMD64 ABI described [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf). The thing that I did not understand was about stack alignment and large operands (`__m256`, `__m512`). Here is the relevant quote:

> The  end  of  the  input  argument  area  shall  be  aligned  on  a 
>   16  (32  or  64,  if `__m256` or `__m512` is passed on stack) byte boundary.
>   In other words, the value `(%rsp+ 8)` is always a multiple of 16 (32 or 64)
>   when control is transferred to the function entry point. The stack
>   pointer, `%rsp`, always points to the end of the latest allocated stack
>   frame.

I interpreted the part about `__m256` and `__m512` as that we push `ymmN`, `zmmN`, but we cannot do this via `push` instruction. Can you explain what does that mean?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/0pzWMV).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Are you talking about `vmovaps ZMMWORD PTR [rsp], zmm0`? I tried it on my `i7-8550U` and got `Illegal instruction exception`. Can you advice what kind of `cpuid` flag is responsible for the instruction?

Comment: @St.Antario Your CPU does not support AVX-512.  You need a CPU that supports `avx512f` in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: @St.Antario Yes :) But also look at the whole code. Particularly the stack alignment with `-64`. Simply put, we cannot push vector registers but we can store registers to memory and we can push constants (though passing by a register is faster). I used AVX-512 but you can work with [AVX2 as well](https://godbolt.org/z/qmVlEA). gcc often allocates all the needed stack in the prolog and than uses explicit stores to do pushes.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Very cool things. Thanks much. I also tested it and without proper alignment the instruction `vmovaps` generates `GP` exception resulting in core dump. This seems to be the reason for such a requirement. If you posted it as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: @St.Antario The alignment is mostly for performance reasons AFAIK, you can use `vmovups` for an unaligned store. Once it was slower, today I don't know. Smaller width stores (128b, 256b maybe?) should be fast even for unaligned stores, but I'm not sure. 512b maybe be still too recent.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, I also checked `vmovups` with unaligned stack pointer. It worked well whereas `vmovaps` failed sometimes with core dump (exactly in cases where the stack pointer was not aligned properly).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Unaligned memory accesses are only slower if they span multiple cache lines as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @fuz IIRC recent uarch can handle split line accesses through split registers. But that seems only for [split loads](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-split-loads) and not for stores?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Stores go through the store buffer.  A split store might just take two cache-write cycles to commit from the store buffer to L1d.  i.e. the store buffer precludes the need for specific split-store buffers.  Inside the store buffer, I think a single store-buffer entry can hold a split store because SB entries are sized for the max store width, not for cache lines.  Or else a split store needs 2 SB entries, but again the buffers are the regular store buffer.  And re: `vmovups`: on any AVX CPU it's equal speed with `vmovaps` *if* the data is aligned at runtime.  Splits hurt some.

Comment: @St.Antario: This is a weird question.  You can always align the stack and then store args the normal way.  You can call that emulating `push` for vector regs if you want.  I thought this was totally obvious (and so did the ABI authors).  Over-aligning the stack without losing the return address is the tricky part, IDK why you're inventing a problem for yourself (no `push zmm`).

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, nice recap!

Comment: @PeterCordes On Windows, it clobbers an extra register that points to an aligned portion of the stack. So you it puts you down 3 GPRs. (rsp, rbp for base pointer, and on ICC - r13 as base pointer for aligned area for spilled vector registers)